# Send SMS with MyPhoneExplorer

Tags: vb.net, sms

Other than twilio if we want to use our android phone to send SMS or make calls we can do it with myphoneexplorer, install Myphoneexplorer both on pc and mobile connect them with wifi Bluetooth or USB then connect your PC and mobile then use the following code to send SMS or any other action you want to do which is mentioned here https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42&sid=04edc8027852e72f7c8679d6f3a137ac

```
 Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPhoneExplorer\MyPhoneExplorer.exe", "action=sendmessage savetosent=1 number=0123456789 text="your text here.%n Any text")
```

make sure application address is correct,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to find solution online but couldn't so I thought to share it for anyone if they need this

```
install Myphoneexplorer both on pc and mobile connect them with wifi Bluetooth or USB then connect your PC and mobile then use the following code to send SMS or any other action you want to do which is mentioned here https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42&sid=04edc8027852e72f7c8679d6f3a137ac

 Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPhoneExplorer\MyPhoneExplorer.exe", "action=sendmessage savetosent=1 number=0123456789 text="your text here.%n Any text")
```

make sure application address is correct,